# Adjust text citation using R package RefManageR

Tags: r, regex, r-markdown, bibtex, citations

I am trying to manage a bibliography using the `R` package `RefManageR` as follows.

```
library(RefManageR)
file.name <- system.file("Bib", "RJC.bib", package="RefManageR")
bib <- ReadBib(file.name)

BibOptions(check.entries = FALSE, bib.style = "authoryear", max.names = 1,
           style = "citation", bibpunct = c("(",")","(",")",";",","))

Cite(bib, c("jennings2013bayesian", "ritchie2012novel"))
[1] "(Jennings, et al., 2013; Ritchie, et al., 2012)"
```

How to adjust the punctuation within the citation so as to get the following desired citation (without comma before et al)?

```
[1] "(Jennings et al., 2013; Ritchie et al., 2012)"
```

There seems to be no option available with the `bibpunct` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression like this:

```
, (?=et al\.)
# match a comma, only when it is followed by et al.
```

This needs to be replaced by a single space then, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9rW21N/1).

---

In `R`:

```
ref <- c("(Jennings, et al., 2013; Ritchie, et al., 2012)")
(ref <- gsub(", (?=et al\\.)", " ", ref, perl=TRUE))
```

---

This yields

```
[1] "(Jennings et al., 2013; Ritchie et al., 2012)"
```